# Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified in build.grade (Project:xxx)

Tags: android, gradle, configuration, twitter-fabric, build-tools

Right now I am trying to integrate Fabric with Crashlytics (https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) into an existing android application.

Following the integration instructions provided by Fabric I add `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to the root directory of my "build.grade (Project.NumenuApp)" file. I click to Sync Gradle, it fails, and I receive this error `Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.` Android studio states that my plugins should be declared at the Module not Project level.

I already have the buildTools set in the "build.grade (Module:app)" file. My question is why is this happening and what can I do to remedy it?  I have posted my code below.  Thanks in advance. - Adrian

build.grade (Project:NumenuApp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all     sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.grade (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.numenu.numenuapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to remove these lines from your `build.gradle (Project:NumenuApp)`. You are using the **wrong file** to apply the plugins.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Also move these lines in your `build.gradle (Module:app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Comment: wow, surprise-surprise, after I updated gradle to 3.3 and androdi-gradle to 2.3.0 I've got exactly the same error, but following your advice I removed `apply plugin: 'idea'` line from the app (and left only in module) and now it's compiling!

Answer (score 3):

this is my `build.gradle(Module:app)` file and I have a working CrashLytics, and I have nothing related to fabrics in my `project.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ws.cs"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "/lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line in your **app.gradle** present or not

**buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"**

Example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kc.care.task"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 23
        versionName "3.7"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```